# Firebase functions errors regarding DNSResolutionsNonbillable, FunctionCallsNonbillable, SocketConnectNonbillable

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase functions NodeJS SDK. Here i can see list of errors on daily basic.

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'DNSResolutionsNonbillable' and limit 'DNS resolutions per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:798895493359'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in
> your project at
> https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=ohfound. Function
> cannot be executed.

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'FunctionCallsNonbillable' and limit 'Function invocations per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:798895493359'., Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'SocketConnectNonbillable' and limit 'Socket connections per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:798895493359'., Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'DNSResolutionsNonbillable' and limit 'DNS resolutions per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:798895493359'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in
> your project at
> https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=ohfound. Function
> cannot be executed.
> {"serviceContext":{"service":"app"},"context":{"reportLocation":{"lineNumber":0,"filePath":"file","functionName":"app"}}

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'SocketConnectNonbillable' and limit 'Socket connections per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:798895493359'., Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'DNSResolutionsNonbillable' and limit 'DNS resolutions per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:798895493359'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in
> your project at
> https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=ohfound. Function
> cannot be executed.
> {"context":{"reportLocation":{"lineNumber":0,"functionName":"app","filePath":"file"}},"serviceContext":{"service":"app"}}

But after doing lots of articles, i am still on same page.
I am not able to got the issue.
Please help to get me understanding about that why this issue is coming.
Also, my apis taking time, every api taking 2-3 seconds whereas it should completed in few milliseconds.

Please provide me the help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Functions limits the number of external addresses (DNSResolutionsNonbillable) as well as many other quotas when billing is not enabled.

Like the error message is telling you, you need to enable billing in your project to raise the quota.

I hope it will help!